# Netbeans: How to use special project parameters in run command line?

Tags: netbeans

I am trying to run a project that requires a specific file for proper execution. So far I have hard-coded the path to that file in the Run configuration's command line, but I would like to use a special project variable for that, that points to the actual directory the project is in.

Example (run command-line):

```
Now: /home/user/netbeansproject/myProject/myspecialfile.gz
Expected: ${project.dir}/myspecialfile.gz
```

Is this possible in Netbeans and if yes: how and where are those parameters documented?

Answer (score -1):

Try this!

```
            if (new File("myspecialfile.gz").exists()) {
                System.out.println(new File("myspecialfile.gz").getAbsolutePath());
            }
```

I would pass the path to main method with command line arguments when the application starts.

```
            if (args.length > 0) {
                System.out.println(new File(args[0].trim()).getAbsolutePath());
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Configuration file needed to"
                        + " run. Provide configuration file's path as argument.");
            }
```

But maybe this solution is not what you're after.

EDIT:

Well if you define new "Run" configuration in your project properties and save it, then it is saved to ..NetBeansProjects/YOUR_PROJECT_NAME/nbproject/configs/your_configuration_name.properties

In that file you can define your commandline arguments like this:
application.args="/somepath/NetBeansProjects/SomeProjectName/myspecialfile.gz"

I don't believe you can add ${somedir} reference to it.

Comment: No this is not the solution I am looking for. I am looking for a parameter that I can add in the Run configuration, which is then passed as commandline eventually, but the later  is not the issue.